# Compile dependent module in Intellij project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I'm a newbie IntelliJ's user therefore I've met some problems.

For example, I have 2 maven project: A & B. Project B is addition source of project A. In Eclipse, I can add source project B into project A by: Java Build Path (project A) -> Source (tab) -> Link Source ... So that I can use every Class in project B from project A.

In IntelliJ, I've imported project B by this way:

**Project Settings -> Modules -> Button (+) -> Import module from external model (select Maven type) -> Next till Finish.**

In order to add module B into module A:

**In tab Dependencies of module A -> Click Button (+) -> 3. Module Dependency -> Select module B from module list -> Apply -> Ok.**

I think this way can help me to link addition source of B into project A (similar to Eclipse).

However, when I added new (or modified) a class in project B and compile project A, I received the error **ClassNotFoundException** from project A. I've tried to compile and make both project B & A, but the exception still remained.

I don't know where I was wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the project structure, click on the A module, go to the Dependencies tab and click the + button beside the dependencies list.
click on the Module Dependency and select the module B. this must resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Hossein, your way is similar what I described above !? It still didn't resolve my problem

Comment: check your dependencies for the Module A, does module B exists in it?

Comment: Module B exists in module A, surely, and module B's scope is Compile in module A.

Comment: The exception you get is about a B class not found in A? or vice versa?

Comment: A B's class not found in A when compiled project A even though I can use (Command + Click) to go to a class B from class A. That's so weird @Hossein

Comment: This is so strange! I did the exact thing you said and it works wonderfully. check if in the project structure, intellij says there is any problem, and see if it suggests to fix it.

Comment: one important note, in the case you have compiling the project using maven will not work. You are not trying to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84587/discussion-between-lee-mcdona-and-hossein).